# (closed) Configuring and using Xdmcp with gdm3 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gdm, xdmcp

On a fresh minimal ubuntu 18.04 installation, I tried to activate and use the gdm3 xdmcp server.

Here are steps I followed:

- **Installation**

I used the normal installation.

"Download updates during installation" was checked

"Install 3rd parties for Gfx/Wifi/.." was not checked.

- **Xdmcp server**

1 . Edit /etc/hosts.allow to set (cf. [Gnome doc.](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#xdmcpsection)).

`ALL: ALL #Wide opened to be sure the problem isn't here`

2 . Edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to set:

`[security]
         DisallowTCP=false
         [xdmcp]
         Enable=true`

3 . Restart gdm

`sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart`

- **Xdmcp client**

`sudo apt install xnest
         Xnest -query localhost -geometry 1024x768 :1`

Unfortunately, I only have a black screen with regular white flash.

Where did I do something wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Christophe C.

Comment: Caution: »XDMCP is inherently insecure. XDMCP is not a ciphered protocol. This may allow an attacker to capture keystrokes entered by a user. XDMCP is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. This may allow an attacker to steal the credentials of legitimate users by impersonating the XDMCP server.« https://cisecurity.org/ CIS Ubuntu Linux Benchmark 20.04

Comment: Hello LiveWireBT,
Thanks a lot for your remark.
The initial plan was to use it thru an ssh tunnel but you are right, I could have the problem you describe locally.
Since my question, I am using in parallel x2go for a machine and vnc over ssh for another. Both match my needs.

Answer (score 2):

In case soemone else finds this question and has problems getting XDMCP to work with gdm3, I managed to get it working by setting gdm3 to use xorg instead of wayland.

*/etc/gdm3/custom.conf*

```
[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: Hello Pathin,

Thanks a lot for those information.

I didn't yet have the time to test it but I will comment when it will be done.

Comment: Worked for after Ubuntu 20.04 -> 22.04 upgrade where x2go X11 forwarding was switched to wayland for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post many months after my initial question but I prefered to confirm my results.

Here they are:

**Working solutions or workarrounds**

- Debian 10.3 xdmcp access with lightdm & LxQT

  ```
   /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-remote-session.conf

   [SeatDefaults]
   xserver-allow-tcp=true
   [XDMCPServer]
   enabled=true
  ```
- Ubuntu 20.4 x2go access with LxQT

**Not working solutions**

- Ubuntu 20.4 xdmcp access with gdm3 & LxQT

  ```
   I did many tries (including the Pathin tip about wayland) under
   18.4 and now... 20.4.
  ```
- Ubuntu 20.4 xdmcp access with lightdm & LxQT

  ```
   I unsuccessfully tried the "lightdm.conf.d/50-remote-session.conf"
   change validated under debian.
  ```

Due to problems I had with xdmcp, I am now using different alternatives to connect remotly.

I hope my tests will help someone.